# How to block all hosts in Windows except urls with wildcards?

Tags: windows, windows-7, internet, firewall

I know about `etc/hosts` file and Windows Firewall. But none of them works with wildcards like `example.com/*`.

Is there a solution which can block access to all hosts from all programs (browsers, command prompt etc.) except whitelisted urls like `example.com/*` or `*.example.com/*` ? And at that block some urls like `example.com/img/*` within allowed url `example.com/*`.

And so that only administrator would be able to change settings of such a "solution", turn it off or uninstall it?

P.S. And compatible with Windows 7